# Skewed Edges with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to replicate this, essentially:

[image]

So basically two 50% `<div>`'s side-by-side, with some form of absolute positioning (I assume) to achieve the left box to go over the top of the right box (the red line is just representing the middle of the viewport)

Any hints? Thanks :)

Comment: framed as you have it?

Answer (score 4):

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  transform: skewX(-20deg) translateX(-40%);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
} 

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 0;
}

Should be pretty simple with CSS3.
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I offer a version without the transformation, using pseudoelement. It is faster and does not distort the text.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box1 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
} 

.box1::after{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, blue 50%, transparent 0);
  content: " ";
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box2 {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.outer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2000px;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1000px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.left__inner {
  background: goldenrod;
  padding: 24px 48px;
  flex: 1;
  transform: skew(45deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right__inner {
  background: #222;
  padding: 24px 48px;
  flex: 1;
  transform: skew(45deg);
}

.left__text,
.right__text {
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  span {
    font-weight: 200;
    font-size: 36px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
}

.left__text {
  color: #3c3c3c;
}

.right__text {
  color: Goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="left__inner">
      <div class="left__text">
        <span> so skewy</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right__inner">
      <div class="right__text">
        <span>span much angle</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this
this is just an example, not a ready-made solution ))

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
</div>

.container {
display: flex;
}

.container div {
width: 50%;
height: 200px;
position: relative;
}

.container .left:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
transform: skewY(-1.5deg);
background: inherit;
}
```